# How to return JSON from serialized JSON in Spring Rest Controller

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-feign

I have a `String` that represents JSON:

`[{"type":"ERROR","message":"some error message"}]`

This `String` is returned by `ex.contentUTF8()` in the following code:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String afterThrowing(FeignException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(ex.status());
        return ex.contentUTF8();
    }

}
```

An HTTP client though doesn't get a JSON response though. Instead, it gets HTML with body of the response being that `String`. How can I instead have JSON returned? Do I need to deserialize that `String`?

**Update**

The response to the client must be exactly the JSON object that represent (would be serialized into) the `String` returned by `ex.contentUTF8()`:

`[{"type":"ERROR","message":"some error message"}]`

So, a wrapper object like `ErrorDto` (as provided in a few answers) will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should return an Object that fit with your JSON representation :

```
public class ErrorDto {
    private String type;
    private String message;
}
```

And :

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorDto afterThrowing(FeignException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return new ErrorDto("your type", "your message");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building from the answer by @Fabien, you can use the `ResponseEntity<Object>` class to return an `application/json` content type response instead. Using `ResponseEntity` essentially gives control over every aspect of the response.

You can try something like this instead:

```
@ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> afterThrowing(FeignException ex) {
    ErrorDto payload = new ErrorDto(ex.status(), ex.contenUTF8());
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(ex.status())
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(payload);
}
```